# Is there any way to open a recently closed tab in Safari in iOS?

Tags: ipad, safari, web-browsing

Is there a way to open a recently closed tab in the Safari browser in iOS? I am specifically looking for a solution that works on the iPad.

*For reference, here is [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26834/) for the Mac.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Hold down on the `+` icon that you use to open a new tab in the upper right corner of Safari and you'll be presented with a list of recently closed tabs. Pick one to re-open.

As far as I know this is an iOS 5+ feature, iPad only.

Comment: Yes. This is iPad exclusive, as iPhone/iPod touch do not have tabbed browsing.

Comment: This works in iPhone 6s with iOS 8. Maybe the older version didn't work in iPhone.